# Cannot convert to date, getting "ORA-01855: AM/A.M. or PM/P.M. required" error message

Tags: sql, oracle

the following code gives me this error message - "ORA-01855: AM/A.M. or PM/P.M. required"

```
SELECT TO_DATE
    ('2/2/2021 8:08:58 PM','MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') "NOW"
     FROM DUAL;
```

If I try to convert to char instead, I get "ORA-01722: invalid number".

```
     SELECT TO_CHAR('2/2/2021 8:08:58 PM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') "NOW"
     FROM DUAL;
```

I don't have much experience with oracle database and have been struggling with it for a while. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Thanks for any help!

Comment: You are trying to convert a string into a string. `to_char` makes sense to convert a date or timestamp to a string, for example `to_char(sysdate, '...')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you probably have `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE` set to something other than English; but not `NLS_LANGUAGE` as that would affect the error message too:

```
alter session set nls_language = 'CZECH';

SELECT TO_DATE
    ('2/2/2021 8:08:58 PM','MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') "NOW"
     FROM DUAL;

ORA-01855: požaduje se AM/A.M. nebo PM/P.M.
```

With just the date language changed:

```
alter session set nls_language = 'ENGLISH';
alter session set nls_date_language = 'CZECH';

SELECT TO_DATE
    ('2/2/2021 8:08:58 PM','MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') "NOW"
     FROM DUAL;

ORA-01855: AM/A.M. or PM/P.M. required
```

You can either change the session setting to English, or change the string to have the language-appropriate AM/PM indicator value:

```
alter session set nls_date_language = 'CZECH';

SELECT TO_DATE
    ('2/2/2021 8:08:58 ODPOLEDNE','MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') "NOW"
     FROM DUAL;

NOW
---------
02-ÚNO-21
```

Or probably most practically and simply, override the session setting in the query:

```
alter session set nls_date_language = 'CZECH';

SELECT TO_DATE
    ('2/2/2021 8:08:58 PM','MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') "NOW"
     FROM DUAL;

NOW
---------
02-ÚNO-21
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b988f945f85bfc63e5896463478cc9db)

Answer (score 0):

You should use TO_CHAR to convert from date to char, not from char:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('2/2/2021 8:08:58 PM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM'),
               'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') "NOW"
  FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: I'm still getting the "ORA-01855: AM/A.M. or PM/P.M. required" error message on TO_DATE conversion though.

Comment: My example has no sense, because no need to convert from char back to char in same format. But if you mean your first query, I don't know - check your mask.